# access denied while increasing max_connections in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database-connection, amazon-rds, workbench, handshake

I am trying to increase max connection capacity to one of our mySQL database from 65 to 1000 in order to resolve database handshake error.

I am trying to set max_connections globarl variable using workbench command line, but it says **access denied**.

FYI, MySQL is hosted at amazon-rds.

Please let me know what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the max_connections parameter is not an ideal solution.

You can Scale up the size of the database and after that check the max_connections value. Definatlty it will inrease .

Refrence video link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoMVlJc8kaI

[image: Please Check the database size]

Comment: Thanks @Yugma, But I need to make it possible with the same RDS tier, I am not allowed to upgrade it. Please advise.